# How to bind Xamarin iOS Obj-C library with marshalling

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, marshalling

I want to study how to bind iOS library with handling pointer to Xamarin.iOS.
It need marshaling.

I prepare such library for test,

**MarshalTest.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    float x,y,z;
} Marshal3D;


@interface MarshalTest : NSObject

-(id)initWithMarshal:(Marshal3D *)marshal;
-(id)initWithMarshals:(Marshal3D *)marshals num:(int)numCoord;

-(void)addMarshal:(Marshal3D *)marshal;
-(void)addMarshals:(Marshal3D *)marshals num:(int)numCoord;

-(int)getMarshals:(Marshal3D **)getMarshals;

-(int) storedNumber;
-(float)checkMarshalValue:(int)index xyz:(int)xyz;

@end
```

and prepare Binding c# codes like this:

**StructsAndEnums.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MarshalTestNet
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Marshal3D
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
    };
}
```

**ApiDefinition.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace MarshalTestNet
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface MarshalTest {

        [Export ("initWithMarshal:")]
        IntPtr Constructor ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Marshal3D marshal);

        [Export ("initWithMarshals:num:")]
        IntPtr Constructor ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Marshal3D marshals, int numCoord);

        [Export ("addMarshal:")]
        void AddMarshal ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Marshal3D marshal);

        [Export ("addMarshals:num:")]
        void AddMarshals ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Marshal3D marshals, int numCoord);

        [Export ("getMarshals:")]
        int GetMarshals ([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Marshal3D getMarshals);

        [Export ("storedNumber")]//, Verify ("ObjC method massaged into getter property", "/Users/kokogiko/Desktop/MarshalTest.h", Line = 32)]
        int StoredNumber { get; }

        [Export ("checkMarshalValue:xyz:")]
        float CheckMarshalValue (int index, int xyz);
    }
}
```

But this not work, just calling

```
var mars3 = new Marshal3D{ 
    x = 1.0f,
    y = 2.0f,
    z = 3.0f
};
var mars = new MarshalTest (mars3);
```

will terminated without showing error message.

How to bind iOS library with marshalling?
There are very less information for doing this...

**[Edited after Rolf's answer]**

Thank you Rolf, I tested many cases so sorry for replying so late.

**1.**

```
[Export ("initWithMarshal:")]
IntPtr Constructor (ref Marshal3D marshal);

[Export ("addMarshal:")]
void AddMarshal (ref Marshal3D marshal);
```

works very well. Thank you!

**2.**

```
[Export ("initWithMarshals:num:")]
IntPtr Constructor (Marshal3D[] marshals, int numCoord);

[Export ("addMarshals:num:")]
void AddMarshals (Marshal3D[] marshals, int numCoord);
```

not works, with showing this error in compile stage:

```
obj/Debug/ios/MarshalTestNet/MarshalTest.g.cs(140,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromNSObjects(params MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject[])' has some invalid arguments
    /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
obj/Debug/ios/MarshalTestNet/MarshalTest.g.cs(140,46): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `MarshalTestNet.Marshal3D[]' expression to type `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject[]'
```

so I change this by myself,

**ApiDefinition.cs**

```
[Export ("addMarshals:num:")]
void AddMarshals (IntPtr marshals, int numCoord);
```

**Extra.cs**

```
public unsafe void AddMarshals (Marshal3D[] marshals) {
    var count = marshals.Length;
    fixed (Marshal3D* ptr = &marshals[0])
        AddMarshals ((IntPtr)ptr, count);         
}
```

this works well.

But, this approach cannot use for

```
-(id)initWithMarshals:(Marshal3D *)marshals num:(int)numCoord;
```

because it is constructor, not allow to add any logic before calling parent method.

Is there any way to fix this?
Using "Factory pattern" is best?

**3.**

```
[Export ("getMarshals:")]
[Internal]
int GetMarshals (IntPtr getMarshals);
```

and

```
public partial class MarshalTest : NSObject {
    public unsafe Marshal3D [] GetMarshals () {
        var count = this.StoredNumber();
        var array = new Marshal3D [count];

        fixed (Marshal3D* ptr = &array[0])
            GetMarshals ((IntPtr) ptr);

        return array;            
    }
}
```

not works.
Terminated without showing any errors in runnig phase.

I think

```
Marshal3D* ptr = &array[0]
```

is a pointer, but

```
-(int)getMarshals:(Marshal3D **)getMarshals;
```

needs pointer-of-pointer.
Isn't it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS binding projects do not support custom marshalling.

But I don't think you need it:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface MarshalTest {

    [Export ("initWithMarshal:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (ref Marshal3D marshal);

    [Export ("initWithMarshals:num:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (Marshal3D[] marshals, int numCoord);

    [Export ("addMarshal:")]
    void AddMarshal (ref Marshal3D marshal);

    [Export ("addMarshals:num:")]
    void AddMarshals (Marshal3D[] marshals, int numCoord);

    [Export ("getMarshals:")]
    [Internal]
    int GetMarshals (IntPtr getMarshals);

    // ...
}
```

However to support GetMarshals nicely, you'll have to add a custom binding (this is typically done in the StructsAndEnums.cs file):

```
public partial class MarshalTest : NSObject {
    public unsafe Marshal3D [] GetMarshals () {
        var count = // how many are there? there's no API to fetch this in your sample
        var array = new Marshal3D [count];

        fixed (Marshal3D* ptr = &array[0])
            GetMarshals ((IntPtr) ptr);

        return array;            
    }
}
```

[**Updated to answer second set of questions**]

1. For the constructor, I think this will work:

   **ApiDefinition.cs**

   ```
   [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
   public partial interface MarshalTest {
       [Export ("initWithMarshals:num:")]
       [Internal]
       IntPtr Constructor (IntPtr marshals, int numCoord);
   }
   ```

   **Extra.cs**

   ```
   public partial class MarshalTest : NSObject {
       public MarshalTest (Marshal3D[] marshals, int numCoord)
           : this (GetPointer (marshals), numCoord)
       {
       }

       static IntPtr GetPointer (Marshal3D[] marshals)
       {
           fixed (Marshal3D* ptr = &marshals[0])
               return (IntPtr) ptr;
       }
   ```

   }
2. You're right, it's expecting a pointer to a array. Try this instead:

   **ApiDefinition.cs**

   ```
   [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
   public partial interface MarshalTest {
       [Export ("getMarshals:")]
       [Internal]
       int GetMarshals (ref IntPtr getMarshals);
   }
   ```

   **Extra.cs**

   ```
   public partial class MarshalTest : NSObject {
       public unsafe Marshal3D [] GetMarshals () {
           var ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
           var count = this.StoredNumber ();
           var array = new Marshal3D [count];

           GetMarshals (ref ptr);

           unsafe {
               Marshal3D* ptr3d = (Marshal3D *) ptr;
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                   array [i] = *ptr3d++;
           }

           return array;            
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Rolf, thank you for answering!
I have some questions, so I edited my first question.

Comment: Thank you, all of them works very well, but one question.
In 1.'s Extra.cs case, returned IntPtr value from GetPointer function is outside of "fixed" block. Aren't there danger of SEGV if GC occures?

Comment: @kochizufan: technically yes, if the GC moves the object, but only if you're using the SGen collector (since the default, Boehm, will not move objects around).

Comment: I see, understand. Thank you!